# Eclipse "open definition" do not work for external library folders

Tags: eclipse, makefile, embedded

I am using Eclipse for embedded system programming. I have a library/ folder that is parallel to the project/ folder. Once I open the Makefile project from Eclipse, from the project/ folder, and I tried to "open definition" of the functions, which are obviously defined in the library/ folder, however, eclipse does not work.

It is the same for the variables which are defined in the source code in library/ folder. If put the mouse cursor to the variables, it shows an error like

> Symbol 'xxxx' could not be resolved

The project compiles well, since it is managed by Makefile.

Is there a way to do some setting in Eclipse such that the the "open definition" works?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by dragging the library/ folder into the project in the Eclipse IDE, and choose

> link to files and folders

in the prompt.